# Align Material UI Grid Items of different length

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I currently have a material ui grid system that looks like the following:

```
<>
      <Typography gutterBottom variant='h6'>
        Add New User{' '}
      </Typography>
      <Grid container spacing={3} alignItems='center' justify='center'>
        <Grid item>
          <Typography variant='body2'>Full name</Typography>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item>
          <TextField
            style={{ width: 400 }}
            fullWidth
            margin='dense'
            id='outlined-basic'
            label='Full name'
            variant='outlined'
          />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <Grid container spacing={3} alignItems='center' justify='center'>
        <Grid item>
          <Typography variant='body2'>Email</Typography>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item>
          <TextField
            style={{ width: 400 }}
            fullWidth
            margin='dense'
            id='outlined-basic'
            label='Email'
            variant='outlined'
          />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
</>
```

I am noticing that because email and full name are different lengths, the grid items do not align in the way I would like them to.  They currently look like the following:

[image]

I would like the grid to look like the following:

[image]

Is there a way to align the grid items like the bottom picture without needing to add a fixed width? that seems to be the only solution I have found but I feel like I'm missing something regarding the grid system.

attached is a code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-bhabha-ur9nm?file=/src/App.js for debugging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added `xs={9}` for text-field and `xs={3}` for the label with `style={{ textAlign: 'right' }}`(not familiar with material-ui so don't know if there's a better way to apply this).

This is the result: https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-euclid-n7y8f

Comment: this seems to be almost exactly what I was looking for. I was curious if it is possible to center the grid

Comment: @RobertTerrell if you can wrap both labels and both inputs in same container, with their parent being a `Grid` (flex) then you can center it

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add `xs sm lg` to your `Grid` component to take advantage of [Auto layout](https://material-ui.com/components/grid/#auto-layout). accoording to the doc:

> The Auto-layout makes the items equitably share the available space.

after applying this change, your items will be aligned properly. you can also check the corrected version here in the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-lake-wyg2e?file=/src/App.js:328-336).